# What happens when casting floating point types to unsigned integer types when the value would overflow?

Tags: c, casting, floating-point, overflow, unsigned

I'm wondering what happens when casting from a floating point type to an unsigned integer type in C when the value can't be accurately represented by the integer type in question. Take for instance

```
func (void)
{
float a = 1E10;
unsigned b = a;
}
```

The value of `b` I get on my system (with `unsigned` on my system being able to represent values from 0 to 2<sup>32</sup>-1) is `1410065408`. This seems sensible to me because it's simply the lowest order bits of the result of the cast.

I believe the behavior of operations such as these is undefined by the standard. Am I wrong? What can I expect in practice if I do things like this?

Also, what happens with signed types? If `b` is of type `int`, I get `-2147483648`, which doesn't really make sense to me.

Comment: To be precise, this is not casting. Assignment causes *implicit conversion*.

Comment: Is there any difference between casting and implicit conversion that would affect the result in this scenario?

Comment: Casting is an *cast operation*, which results in *explicit conversion*. Same rules are used for implicit and explicit conversions, but they are different things in standard.

Comment: You can get `-2147483648` because this is what the instruction of your processor produces, or you can get something else on a different processor, or you can get strange results because your processor is using a 64-bit signed conversion instruction to implement what is a 32-bit unsigned conversion in the source code. Being undefined behavior, the compiler does not have to be consistent. See http://blog.frama-c.com/index.php?post/2013/10/09/Overflow-float-integer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What happens when casting floating point types to unsigned integer types when the value would overflow (?)

*undefined behavior* (UB)

---

In addition [@user694733](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46929035/2410359) fine answer, to prevent *undefined behavior* caused by out of range `float` to `unsigned` code can first test the `float` value.

Yet testing for the range is tricky, for unsigned types and especially for signed types.  The detail is that all conversions and constants prior to the integer conversion must be *exact*.   FP math near the limits needs to be exact too.

Examples:

Conversion to a 32-bit unsigned is valid for the range -0.999... to 4294967295.999....

Conversion to a 32-bit 2's complement signed is valid for the range -2147483648.999... to  2147483647.999....

---

```
// code uses FP constants that are exact powers-of-2 to insure their exact encoding.

// Form a FP constant that is exactly UINT_MAX + 1
#define FLT_UINT_MAX_P1 ((UINT_MAX/2 + 1)*2.0f)

bool convert_float_to_unsigned(unsigned *u, float f) {
  if (f > -1.0f && f < FLT_UINT_MAX_P1) {
    *u = (unsigned) f;
    return true;
  }
  return false;  // out of range
}


#define FLT_INT_MAX_P1 ((INT_MAX/2 + 1)*2.0f)
bool convert_float_to_int(int *i, float f) {
  #if INT_MIN == -INT_MAX
  // Rare non 2's complement integer
  if (fabsf(f) < FLT_INT_MAX_P1) {
    *i = (int) f;
    return true;
  }
  #else
  // Do not use f + 1 > INT_MIN as it may incur rounding
  // Do not use f > INT_MIN - 1.0f as it may incur rounding
  // f - INT_MIN is expected to be exact for values near the limit
  if (f - INT_MIN > -1 && f < FLT_INT_MAX_P1) {
    *i = (int) f;
    return true;
  }
  #endif 
  return false;  // out of range
}
```

---

Pedantic code would take additional steps to cope with the rare `FLT_RADIX 10`.

`FLT_EVAL_METHOD`, which allows for `float` math be calculated at higher precision, may play a role, yet so far I do not see it negatively affecting the above solution.

Answer (score 2):

In both cases value is out of range, so it's undefined behaviour.

> #### 6.3.1.4 Real floating and integer
>
> 1. When a finite value of real floating type is converted to an integer type other than `_Bool`,
>      the fractional part is discarded (i.e., the value is truncated toward zero). If the value of
>      the integral part cannot be represented by the integer type, the behavior is undefined. <sup>61)</sup>
>
> <sub>61) The remaindering operation performed when a value of integer type is converted to unsigned type
>   need not be performed when a value of real floating type is converted to unsigned type. Thus, the
>   range of portable real floating values is (−1, U*type*_MAX+1).</sub>

To make this well defined code, you should check that value is within possible range before doing the conversion.

Comment: A note to the question "What can I expect in practice": When the system supports integer types bigger than the target type (e.g. uint64), you may be lucky that assembler **first converts from fp to this bigger integer type** before the least significant bits are separated to form the final value. So your code may work since increasing values simply cause an **integer wrap around**. But there is also a chance, that conversion causes the **FP exception** "invalid operation" (and if masked, the result is **uintxx_max**). -- Be aware: the behavior may change in any next version of your compiler.