# Weird Behavior of large float in printf() and assigned to an int

Tags: c, floating-point, int, printf

As per my calculation to convert the float values into the binary value stored by the computer (Sign, Exponent, Mantissa format), out of 32 bits, 1 bit is reserved for sign, 8 bits for Exponent.

So only 23 bits are remaining to represent the number.

So I am thinking that the range of float values with correct behavior would be only 0-0xffffff (basically only 3 bytes value) and not 0-0xffffffff.
Is this correct?

And is the weird behavior of the below code related to this concept?

```
int main(void)
{
    float a=2555555555;
    printf("%f\n",a);
    int b = a;
    printf("%d",b);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
a = 2555555584.000000
b = -2147483648
```

Comment: "So only 23 bits are remaining to represent the number." --> with most FP values the leading bit is an implied 1, so 24 bits to represent the significand.

Answer (score 3):

The first thing to note about your program is that the value `2555555555` exceeds the bounds of a (signed) 32-bit integer type. From the output of your program it seems that `int` is a 32-bit type on your system, so `2555555555` cannot be an `int`.

According to the standard, `2555555555` will then be either a `long int` or `long long int`, depending on whether `long int` is big enough.

The next relevant part is this:

> When a value of integer type is converted to a real floating type, if the value being
>   converted can be represented exactly in the new type, it is unchanged. **If the value being
>   converted is in the range of values that can be represented but cannot be represented
>   exactly, the result is either the nearest higher or nearest lower representable value**, chosen
>   in an implementation-defined manner. If the value being converted is outside the range of
>   values that can be represented, the behavior is undefined.

(Emphasis mine.)

Because `2555555555` requires at least 32 bits of mantissa to be represented exactly, it does not fit into a 32-bit `float`. That is why `a` ends up containing `2555555584`, the closest representable value of type `float`.

For `int b = a;` this section applies:

> When a finite value of real floating type is converted to an integer type other than `_Bool`,
>   the fractional part is discarded (i.e., the value is truncated toward zero). **If the value of
>   the integral part cannot be represented by the integer type, the behavior is undefined.**

(Emphasis mine.)

`2555555584`, the integer value in question, cannot be represented by a signed 32-bit `int`. This part of your code has undefined behavior.

Comment: Thanks for your good explanation. But how does 2555555584 is the closest representable value? If 2555555555 cannot be represented, the same should apply to 2555555584 right?

Comment: And coming to second part..a = 2555555584 which in binary is ‭10011000010100101010111100000000‬. So when it is assigned to int, it should think it as a negative number and should take the 2's complement of it. i.e. (sign)1100111 10101101 01010001 00000000. This value in decimal is -‭1739411712‬.‬ So why is it printing -2147483648 ? If my explanation is wrong, please correct me.

Comment: @PavankumarSV `2555555584` is `10011000010100101010111100000000` in binary, which can be represented exactly using 24 bits of mantissa (`100110000101001010101111`) and an exponent of `8`. IEEE 754 `float`s have 24 bits of precision in the mantissa: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format#IEEE_754_single-precision_binary_floating-point_format:_binary32

Comment: @PavankumarSV I repeat: "**If the value of the integral part cannot be represented by the integer type, the behavior is undefined.**"

Answer (score 0):

The integer overflowed, as the max value of a 32-bit integer is 2,147,483,647.

Converting to e.g. `unsigned int` works:

```
printf("%u", (unsigned int)2555555555.f);  // prints 2555555584
```

Comment: @krisz..a = 2555555584 which in binary is ‭10011000010100101010111100000000‬. So when it is assigned to int, it should think it as a negative number and should take the 2's complement of it. i.e. (sign)1100111 10101101 01010001 00000000. This value in decimal is -‭1739411712‬.‬ So why is it printing -2147483648 ? If my explanation is wrong, please correct me.

Comment: When you assign between different types of numbers, a semantic conversion is made. If you interpret a float as in int without conversion (`*(int*)&a`) then would happen what you described. Although the result is 1326994095.

Comment: @krisz `*(int*)&a` causes undefined behaviour due to strict aliasing violation

Answer (score 0):

> So only 23 bits are remaining to represent the number.

This is incorrect. There's one hidden bit so the significand part is 24 bits long

> So I am thinking that the range of float values with correct behavior would be only 0-0xffffff (basically only 3 bytes value) and not 0-0xffffffff. Is this correct?

This is also incorrect. Did you forgot the exponent part? `float` can represent any values that are in the form *significand × 2<sup>exponent</sup>* where significand lies in the range [0, 2<sup>24</sup> - 1]

> But how does 2555555584 is the closest representable value? If 2555555555 cannot be represented, the same should apply to 2555555584 right?

2555555584 = 0x9852AF × 2<sup>8</sup> so it's entirely representable in single precision, as the significand contains exactly 24 bits

That's the behavior up to the first printf. After that you're casting a float value outside int's range to int which invokes undefined behavior. See [C What happens when casting floating point types to unsigned integer types when the value would overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46928840/995714)